# Dimensions problem with logits and labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

i have a problem with a Keras model. The code :

Here's the first inputs, X is the images, their dimension will be showed after

```
print(len(X), len(target))
1500 1500
```

```
X = np.array(X, dtype="float") / 255.0
target = to_categorical(target,10)
target = np.array(target)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,
                                                    target,
                                                    test_size = 0.2,
                                                    random_state = 777)

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train,
                                                  y_train,
                                                  test_size = 0.4,
                                                  random_state = 777)
```

Then i show all the dimensions of my three datasets:

```
print("x_train shape = ", X_train.shape)
print("y_train shape = ", y_train.shape)
print("\nx_validation shape = ", X_val.shape)
print("y_validation shape = ", y_val.shape)
print("\nx_test shape = ", X_test.shape)
print("y_test shape = ", y_test.shape)

x_train shape =  (720, 150, 150, 3)
y_train shape =  (720, 10)

x_validation shape =  (480, 150, 150, 3)
y_validation shape =  (480, 10)

x_test shape =  (300, 150, 150, 3)
y_test shape =  (300, 10)
```

Here's we can see these dimensions seems normal

```
model=Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=96,kernel_size=(11,11),strides=(4,4),padding="valid",activation="relu",input_shape=(150,150,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256,kernel_size=(5,5),strides=(1,1),padding="valid",activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding="valid",activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding="valid",activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(4096,input_shape=(227,227,3),activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(4096,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(1000,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
```

and here's my error :

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train,
                    y_train,
                    epochs=30)
```

```
Epoch 1/30
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-95c7b541e6c9> in <module>()
      4 history = model.fit(X_train,
      5                     y_train,
----> 6                     epochs=EPOCHS)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:756 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:203 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:152 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:256 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:1537 categorical_crossentropy
        return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4833 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1134 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 10) and (None, 2, 2, 10) are incompatible
```

i saw some topics about this kind of error but any helped me precisely..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is raised because your output shape is different from your label shape.

The label shape, as you have provided, is `(None, 10)`, which is correct.

The output shape, as the error message showed, is `(None, 2, 2, 10)` is incorrect.

The reason that your output shape is wrong is because before your first `Dense` layer and after your last `Conv2D` layer you did not have a `Flatten` layer to flatten your output from the last `Con2D` layer. (For how to implement `Flatten` layer please refer to the keras document, it is very easy.)

The reason you need a `Flatten` layer is because keras' `Dense` layer will not automatically flatten a layer with shape, say, (10, 10, 30) to (10 * 10 * 30). So after your last `Conv2D` layer, the shape of your output is like (2, 2, 384) and after the first dense layer it will be (2, 2, 4096), and after the last one it will be (2, 2, 10). In other words, keras `Dense` layer will be applied to the last dimension of the input it received.

Some related points:

1. You do not need to specify `input_shape` for the dense layer.
2. For all such shape related errors, use `model.summary()` to check your model is a good way for you to spot where you messed up in your NN structure.